# jQuery .toggleClass() is working locally but not on the remote server

Tags: jquery, remote-server, pageload, jquery-hover, toggleclass

Please help. This code works locally but not after I upload it to the remote server. It does not seem to be a cdn issue because I put an alert statement in as a test. The second statement is for a separate page and it works there. I am referencing the jQuery via cdn at the bottom of my html page with a link to my javascript file below that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.thmb').hover(function () {
        var x = $('.thmb').index(this);
        $('.info_art').eq(x).toggleClass("hover-animation");
    });
    $('.thmbs_pdg_div a').click(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var divname = this.name;
        $("#" + divname).show().siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

Here is the code I added at the end of the html page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="javascript/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">  <\/script>')</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/artwork.js"></script>
```

Here is the url of the page: http://www.kipdeeds.com/artwork_page.html

Some additional information about the page that is not working: There are seven categories and the text for each category are sprites (e.g. "on paper", "new art", etc.). When one hovers the position should shift revealing a new image of the text with an arrow icon. The program I was writing would allow the corresponding image icons to enact the same affect in the sprite displaying the text.

For now I will not alter the code until I get feedback (ideas better than mine).

Comment: I'd double check the link to include jQuery is right.

Comment: What browser are you using and have you looked in the console to check for the error message that is most likely there?  I'm guessing as @SpaceBeers is mentioning that your get a `$ is undefined` or some other message indicating jquery isn't present.

Comment: @Jared - Yep. Nothing browser side should change by moving off the local.

Comment: I am a newbie to programing. As far as I can tell I don't get errors in the console related to this script.I am not seeing the script performing an action. Again everything works well locally.

Comment: I have been testing in both chrome and firefox.

Comment: How about the stylesheet? Are you sure you have the latest version of *it* uploaded to your server?

Comment: I did re-style the page replacing the table with divs and the styling seems to work. I have been going a bit crazy with changes between bbedit and fileZilla but here is the url. I need some sleep can't think straight. http://www.kipdeeds.com/artwork_page.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS is fine.

The problem is the disparity with your CSS and your images.  Here's you're CSS:

```
a.art_paper {
    background: url("../assets/artwork_page/on_paper.gif") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 33px;
    width: 95px;
}

a:hover, #artwork_main_div .hover-animation {
    background-position: 0 -100px;
}
```

Her's your image: [image] (95px x 20px)

You are infinitely repeating your background-image, which happens to be 20px high. When the `.hover-animation` class is active, it's sliding the background down by 100px, which takes you the 5th (100/20=5) vertical iteration of the image... which looks exactly like the original.

[image]

Comment: I'll try changing the css position. It is still puzzling then why it would work locally? Thank you Ayman for checking into this.

Comment: you are definitely on to something though I have not solved it yet. My sprites are 40px vertical the area shown is 20px. When I added `background: no-repeat` and changed the `a:hover` to `background-position: 0 -20px;` It still worked locally it hovered in the remote view but did not show any content. I also tried a half step `background-position: 0 -10px;`. I used this [tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/basic-link-rollover-as-css-sprite/) as a guide.

Comment: The problem is that you're *not* using a sprite... at least on your server.  Instead, you have a single image that reads, "On Paper".  Check it out: http://www.kipdeeds.com/assets/artwork_page/on_paper.gif

Comment: You are correct; it seems the server is handling the .gif differently than it is locally. However, I am still confused about why this is happening and what to do about it. Without the javascript `a:hover` worked fine on the sprite on the server now it seems it is not recognizing the hidden part of the sprite.

Comment: Try re-uploading the images. The images you have on the server are **not** sprites.

Comment: you are absolutely correct. It is very strange, in a fit of desperation last night, I renamed my remote folder and uploaded my local version and yet the .gifs are not the same. I can't explain this at all. However, I switched the .gifs to the sprite version and now it works. I may have also been having issues with filezilla.I must say this is the first site I designed and I used all kinds of "bad" techniques as I was learning. Only later would I correct code as I learned something. This was a test as a part of that process. I am getting better.Thank you so much.